# Setting Facebook Publish Stream URLs

Tags: facebook, facebook-wall

I am using facebook publishStream method in Facebook FBML Application, some other developer worked on it before me. I am using it some thing like this

```
Facebook.streamPublish('Publish Shirt Tale. <?php echo $canvasURL.'?req=tale-details&tale_id='.$tale_id?>', attachment);
```

But there is another url that is under the shared image, see below image for more info
[image]

So as in image there is encircle link, so that points towards some other page while I want it to the first page of app. It currently goes to a page some thing like this: http://apps.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxx

so can any one tell that where can I specify that URL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: check the variable of $canvasURL ad $tale_id that what are the values in them. it may happen that they are pointing to any other application. just echo those variable and see their values

Comment: those are fine but I think there is some problem in some settings, but don't understand from where I can set this

Comment: @Bartek: This is just an image in attachment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per facebook is [deprecating all FBML apps soon](http://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/), I would advise you to [look here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/), and try and create a dialog in this way. I can give you the script I'm currently using, where the link you circled directs to my app's home page. a note should be made- my app is an Iframe app.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    attachment: {
      name: 'name',
      caption: 'caption',
      source: 'picture.jpg',
      picture: 'picture.jpg',
      description: 'description',
      href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname'
    },
    action_links: [
      { text: 'name', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname' }
    ]
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
    </script>
```

If you however you would like to keep your app in the FBML form, try this code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    FB.ui(
  {
    method: 'stream.publish',
    attachment: {
      name: 'name',
      caption: 'caption',
      source: 'picture.jpg',
      picture: 'picture.jpg',
      description: 'description',
      href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php'
    },
    action_links: [
      { text: 'name', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/appname/index.php' }
    ]
  },
  function(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
);
    </script>
```

You need to understand the difference between Iframe and FBML apps: While Iframe apps make the user stay in the same page all the time, and only the content in the Iframe is changes, FBML application actually move the user from page to page. Because of this, when specifying links in FBML apps, it is important to use the `http://apps.facebook.com/appname/page` link instead of the `http://www.yoursite.com/page` link.

Example links:

1. A link on your site: `http://www.yoursite.com/game1.php`
2. Would look like this in an FBML app: `http://apps.facebook.com/appname/game1.php`

Answer (score 1):

ok Hafiz then try this code.

```
FB.ui({
    method: 'stream.publish',
    message:'hello',
    attachment: {
      name: title,

      caption: "I'm running!",
      media: [{
        type: 'image',
        href: 'http://www.yoursite.com/',
        src: 'http://www.yoursite.com/images/working.jpeg'
      }]
    },
    action_links: [{
      text: 'Get your percentage',
      href: 'http://www.yoursite/'
    }],
    user_message_prompt: 'Tell your friends about Get your percentage:'
  });
```

Comment: Don;t forget to initialize the JavaScript SDK Before you do. http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/fb.init/